# What should be the best approach to test iOS SDK public functions with number of real devices and iOS version?

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, xctest

I am looking into the approaches for testing the iOS SDK public functions without explicitly developing an dedicated app to test the SDK public function.

**Approach which did not worked:** We can develop an app and include button's and on clicking that button- SDK public function can be called and verified but cons of this approach is more development time and maintenance of the test App.

**Unit Testing Approach but looks it wont work:** We can write unit test but it wont cover a full flow scenario Functionality hence we can not take this approach also If we write integrated test then we can not run on real devices.

**Can we somehow test the iOS SDK public functions using some white-box technique and can also catch the environmental (iOS versions/devices) issues. I want to build a complete automation suite on top of it.**

Please share your thought on this.

Comment: Atul, welcome to StackOverflow. Which "iOS SDK public functions" do you mean? Who wrote them? Please update your question (if it lets you) to be more specific.

Comment: @JonReid  Thanks Jon for your reply. I cant give this information. But yeah it is more of a very generic question. Like whenever any company release their SDK in to market so before releasing the product how do they verify their iOS SDK functionality. For example: For hitting the Android SDK public functions (may be a very simple case Log-In & Log Out)- Espresso driver can be used to hit the public functions for Log-In and Log-out directly but I do not know whether we can do the same in iOS or not. I am looking for white-box testing technique for iOS SDK

Comment: So it sounds like the answer to "who wrote them" is: "we wrote them, and want to test them."